# How To Tell What Software Tool Created An EXE File?

Tags: visual-studio, delphi, ide, exe, header-files

Is there a way to determine what software tool was used to create a specific exe file? For example I'd like to find out if Delphi or Visual Studio or [Fill in the Blank] was used to create a program.

**UPDATE:**

I'm using a program called FoxtrotOne from [www.enablesoft.com](http://www.enablesoft.com) that uses a script and a datafile. The program acts just like a person sitting at the keyboard doing data updates. I've been continually monitoring the task manager and the FoxtroneOne.exe and the memory continues to climb as it loops through the dataset.

I've been told by the tech support guy to close IE after every 100 records because it's holding onto memory. My script interacts with a web application.

I'm convinced that there is a memory leak within FoxtrotOne. If I could determine what IDE they used I could suggest what low level tool they should use. For example if Delphi created this exe then I would suggest they install madExcept to check for memory leaks.

**FINAL UPDATE:**

I used [Exeinfo PE](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/ExEinfo-PE-Download-38188.html) to detrmine FoxtrotOne was created with Visual Basic 5.0 - 6.0

Comment: Most stupid solution ever: open the file in Notepad. Sometimes it gives information about which application generated it.

Comment: You can try finding a copy of the `PEiD` tool.

Comment: If you think you've got any hope of persuading them to use ME, then you'll be able to ask them what dev tool they used.

Comment: A quick hex-editor investigation of the release version of a program I wrote with Visual Studio contains the string "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator" embedded in it. Have you tried a similar examination? I can't imagine there's a generic way because it depends on what the compiler creators decide to include.

Comment: There is a nice tool called ExeInfo PE (Free) you can get it here: http://www.exeinfo.antserve.com/

Comment: @Shambhala, it is only free as free beer :-(

Comment: If you're going to try and convince them there's a leak by identifying the compiler used and recommending a tool, why aren't you just asking them what compiler they use? If they're not going to tell you that, they're not going to listen to you recommend a leak finder.

Comment: I'd like to know where this free beer is. I don't care about the software, I just want the free beer.

Comment: @David Heffernan, [here it is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Free_Beer.jpg) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the EXE in a hex editor (such as HxD), and you might get a lot of clues. For instance, if you find a lot of VCL-related strings like `TLabel`, `TForm`, etc., it is probably an Embarcadero tool.

[image]

You might also open the EXE in a resource editor (such as XN Resource Editor) to get more clues:

[image]